# If $f$ is increasing on some infinite interval, then $f$ is positively unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The following is my attempt to prove, using the Archimedean property, that if $f$ is increasing on some infinite interval $I$, then $f$ is positively unbounded. I am dubious however as to its validity...

**My Proof**

Suppose otherwise, i.e. $f$ is bounded. Let $A = \{f(x): x \in I\}$. Since $A \neq \varnothing$, there is a supremum $\alpha \geq f$. For any $a$ there exists $c > a$ in $I$ such that $f(c) > f(a)$. Thus $f(c)$ is an upper bound of $A$. But $f(c)$ is in $A$ so $f(c) = \alpha$. For any $a,c$ in $I$ however there exists $a < b < c$ such that $f(a) < f(b) < f(c)$. By reasoning similar to the above (applied exclusively to $a,b$) it can be established that $f(b) = \alpha$. So $f(b) = \alpha = f(c)$. Contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by "positively unbounded"? What about the function $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$? 

The error in your proof is that $c$ depends on $a$. There is not necessarily one point $c$ that satisfies $f(c)>f(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: That there is $x$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ here?

Comment: Any arbitrary positive number. But you've pointed out my error. The counterexample is great too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"For any $a$ there exists $c > a$ in $I$ such that $f(c) > f(a)$. Thus $f(c)$ is an upper bound of $A$."

No, $f(c)$ is an upper bound of $B=f(J)$, where $J=\{x:x\le c\}$, but that is not $A$.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is not true. For example, consider $$f(x) = 1-e^{-x}, x\ge 0.$$

The function is increasing on $[0,\infty),$ and it is bounded by $y=1.$

Comment: Another counter-example $f(x)=\arctan x$.....+1

Answer (score 0):

Staying in the realm of rational functions: $f(x)=x/(1+x)$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ yet $0\le f(x)< 1$ for all $x\ge 0.$